# How can we link Splunk with BMC ITAM

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Is there any options available to link BMC ITAM with Splunk to create alerts and dashboards for monitoring on incidents?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few standard ways to link a product to Splunk.  Depending on what you want from the product, you may need more than one of these.

1. Look for an app in apps.splunk.com for the product.
2. Install the universal forwarder on the product servers to forward logs and other data files to Splunk.
3. Have the product send syslog to Splunk.
4. Build a modular input that uses the product's API to extract data.
5. Use the DB Connect app to read the product's SQL database.